# Implementation of an OkHttp singleton for Android

Tags: java, beginner, android, http, singleton

I'm new to Android programming. I am going to make lots of HTTP requests: 500, 1k, 2k, 10k.

I have tried to create a singleton class for OkHttp. I wrote this:

```
public class OkSingleton extends OkHttpClient {

private  static  OkSingleton minstance;
private final OkHttpClient myClient;

private OkSingleton (){
    myClient= new OkHttpClient();
}

public static synchronized  OkSingleton getMinstance(){

    if (minstance==null){
        minstance=new OkSingleton();
    }

    return minstance;
}}
```

Can you show me my mistakes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You don't need to create new instance of `OkHttpClient`. Remove it.
2. You can use [Initialization-on-demand holder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) pattern to create singleton in Java. No need to use `synchronized` block
3. Change coding style in your code. Remove `m` before `instance` variable. See [naming convention](https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/code-style#follow-field-naming-conventions).

Here is the code:

```
public class OkSingleton extends OkHttpClient {
    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final OkSingleton instance = new OkSingleton();
    }

    public static OkSingleton getInstance() {
        return LazyHolder.instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the purpose of having `LazyHolder` class when you can directly have `instance` object under `OkSingleton` class ?

Comment: @Jabbar_Jigariyo TL;DR, to remove `synchronized`. More detail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom

Comment: Thank you for help. Lazy Holder is thread-safe ?

Comment: @Castiel Yes. It's supported by JVM.

Comment: how to check that it working as singleton because i got GC blocked error